# How to enumerate over a list in python backwards with index(From the end to the beginning)

Tags: python, loops, reverse

I'm like to iterate over a list of received data from Digikey api any didn't have much luck googling since the function `enumerate(reversed(part.standard_pricing))` just doesn't work and you can't reverse the `part.standard_pricing` for some reason
Something like that is desired:

```
for b_idx in range(part.standard_pricing, -1, -1):
            print(f"Test at: {b_idx} , Q: {part.standard_pricing[b_idx].break_quantity}")
            if PCountQ >= part.standard_pricing[b_idx].break_quantity:
                parts_df['PRICE_PER_PCB_Q'][idx] = part.standard_pricing[b_idx].unit_price * PCountQ
                break
```

But range doesn't work on list either...

I'd like to do that:

```
for b_idx, price_break in enumerate(part.standard_pricing):
```

just instead start from the end of `part.standard_pricing` and have the index decrease instead of increase

Any idea on how to do that pythonically?

Answer (score 12):

You can call `enumerate` on the list, then convert the enumerate object to list, it will give list of tuples where each tuple will have index and value, finally iterate on `reversed` list.

```py
data = [1,2,3,4]
for i,d in reversed(list(enumerate(data))):
    print(i,d)
    
3 4
2 3
1 2
0 1
```

*In case, you don't want another copy of the sequence in the memory, you can create your custom generator*.

```py
def reverseEnum(data: list):
    for i in range(len(data)-1, -1, -1):
        yield (i, data[i])
for i, d in reverseEnum([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print(i, d)
    
3 4
2 3
1 2
0 1
```

Comment: While this works (+1), it creates a new list in memory just to iterate over something that is already in memory.

Comment: yeah it creates the list before actually iterating it, because `enumerate` object is a `generator` so can not be reversed, in that case, a custom generator can be created.

Comment: Yeah what ever this seem effective and simple which python is all about thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `reverse`ing the `enumerate`d list, we can also `enumerate` the `reversed` list and use a bit of math for the index:

```
the_list = ["zeroth", "first", "second"]
length = len(the_list)

for j, value in enumerate(reversed(the_list), start=1):
    # "the" index is this
    i = length - j
    print(i, value)
```

to get

```
2 second
1 first
0 zeroth
```

You can also go for `i = -j` and get `-1, -2, -3`, which, when indexes, gives the same values as the `2, 1, 0` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to reverse or copy the list. Just use it in place and index it from the end:

```
for b_idx in range(len(part.standard_pricing)-1, -1, -1):
    print(f"Test at: {b_idx} , Q: {part.standard_pricing[b_idx].break_quantity}")
```

This is a mirror of the Python antipattern

```
    for b_idx in range(len(part.standard_pricing)):
```

but since it is a mirror you can consider it an *anti-*antipattern.

Comment: Thanks that seems effective for some reason I remember trying this mostly coming from the C world but it didn't work for me :)

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it.